# functions of lib file input no work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need zoom delete on my file,the problem is that these functions are in the [bootstrap-fileinput](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) library when trying to use them is where it gives me error, I want this to work mostly zoom and delete.

[image]

In the picture I have a pdf but the button of zoom dont have icon and when I i do click on the button have a error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.modal is not a function
    at t._zoomPreview (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-core.js:338), <anonymous>:11:2213)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-core.js:338), <anonymous>:11:2744)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-core.js:4641)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-core.js:4309)
```

The implementation is simple:

```
<link href="../../../bower_components/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../../bower_components/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control"
         type="file"
         file-model="photo_document"
         id="photo_document"
         name="photo_document[]"
         data-preview-file-type="text" required>
  <script>
    console.log(photo_document);
    $("#photo_document").fileinput({'showUpload':false});
  </script>
</div>
```

**I RETURNED ALL COMPONENTS, TO TRY IT ALL WELL. THE ERROR CONTINUES, ICON ONLY APPEARS.**

```
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="../../../bower_components/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../../bower_components/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is bootstrap loaded ?

Comment: yes is loaded, I'm using angular and directives, for template I use bootstrap.

Comment: `.modal` is a bootstrap function... Check if BS is loaded before `fileinput.js` -- Else I don't know.

Comment: Is jQuery loaded?

Comment: Yes jquery and bootstrap is loaded.